# Twilio not speaking street address correctly

Tags: twilio, text-to-speech, twilio-api

We've created an app to make outbound calls using Twilio.  If we have a section of text that's a street address such as "1234 2nd St", Twilio will say it as "one two three four two en dee es tee".  Is there a tag or something we can put around it so Twilio say it correctly as an address (Drive instead of dee arr/Boulevard insteasd of bee el vee dee, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

For the address acronyms you can replace it with the full name

```
$address = preg_replace('/\ASt\Z/', 'Street', $address);
$address = preg_replace('/\Adr\Z/', 'Drive', $address);
```

and for the the street address, replace 2nd with second etc like so:

```
$address = preg_replace('/\A2nd\Z/', 'Second', $address);
```